# Search not working need some advice

Tags: c, binary-search

Working on a binary search. The code below should explain what I'm trying to do. The user inputs a word and then a binary search is implemented to search a wordlist. Problem is the binary search. It's running but it's not finding the word in the wordlist even though I know its there. I know the code could be better but it should work. Anyone shed any light?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char dictionary[400000][45];

int main(void)
{
FILE infile;
int i=0;
int num;
int index;
char buffer[45];
char userword[45];

fp1 = fopen("C:/Users/Aaron/ProgrammingAssignment/dictionary.txt","rb");

    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
    printf("The dictionary file did not open\n");
    exit(0);
    }

    else
    {
    printf("Dictionary file is open\n");
    }

    while(fgets(buffer,45, fp1)!=NULL)
        {
            strcpy(wordlist[i],buffer);
            //printf("Line %d: %s",i,wordlist[i]);
            i++;
        }

    printf("Your wordlist is now in the dictionary array");

    do
    {
    //fscanf(fp2,"%s", userword);
    printf("Enter a word to be spell checked: ");
    fgets(userword, 43, stdin);

    //and do a binary search
    index = BinarySearch(userword,0,i);
    if(index > -1)
        printf("%s was found in the wordlist", userword);
    else
        printf("%s was not found in the dictionary", wordcheck);
    }
    while(wordlist != NULL);

    if(index>-1) //The word was found
   {
      printf("That is correctly spelled\n");
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("That word is spelt wrong\n");
   }


return 0;
}

int BinarySearch(const char userword[],int left,int right)
  { int high = 400000;   
    int low = 0; 
    int target; 
    int count = 0;

    while (high >= low)   
      { target = low + ((high - low) / 2);

        // show tries for demonstration only
        printf("%d, ",target);

        if (strcmp(userword, wordlist[target]) < 0)
          high = target -1;
        else if (strcmp(userword, wordlist[target]) > 0)
          low = target + 1;
        else 
        return target;
      }
    return -1; 
  }
```

Comment: I take it the initial input in `dictionary.txt` is ordered?

Comment: Yes it's already ordered text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binary search function is ignoring the values `left` and `right` that are passed in.

It shouldn't.

It should probably start:

```
int BinarySearch(const char userword[], int left, int right)
{
    int high = right;   
    int low = left;
```

---

You should close the dictionary after you finish reading it.

You need to consider whether `right` is the index of the last valid element or 'one after the index of the last element'.  This might mean you need to pass `i - 1` in the call to the function.

You should consider calling `strcmp()` once and capturing its return value; it is relatively expensive:

```
int rc = strcmp(userword, wordlist[target]);

if (rc == 0)
    return target;
else if (rc < 0)
     high = target - 1;
else
     low = target - 1;
```

Comment: Right should be the index of the last valid element. I'm not really sure about using binary search could you explain a bit more?

Comment: `i` in the main program is the index of the first invalid element in the array, so the call in `main()` should probably be `index = BinarySearch(userword, 0, i-1);`.  The other possible problem might be the loop termination condition: `while (high >= low)`.  I've not sat down and worked out whether this is correct for your code.  But I do know (from reading Jon Bentley's 'Programming Pearls' and 'More Programming Pearls') that binary search is very tricky to get 100% right.  You should test on 'dictionaries' of size 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 words before going for the full size dictionary.